# How to solve the issue of Local Users and Group is missing in Computer Management in the server?

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am attempting to install SharePoint 2019. I had a new VM where I installed the Prereqs and created the User Accounts. I need to assign the spAdmin account to the Administrator group however I cannot do anything as my Administrator Account is a Domain Controller.

What are the proper steps to solve the issue of Local Users and Group missing in Computer Management in the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have being reading around and come across some articles or forums that stay you can enable Local Users and Groups within, but its not recommended.Others say use the domain controller Administrator to create another Administrator Account to do it. I don't really understand the pros and cons of each. So what would be the best/safest approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing SharePoint on a domain controller is not supported. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/server-install/certain-installation-scenarios-are-not-supported. Note the article references SharePoint 2013, but it is applicable to 2013+.

Comment: Thanks for this link. What would you think is the best way to approach this?